# How do i get a choice from an selector to the json document?

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, drop-down-menu

How do I make it possible to choose a country in the drop down menu and get the data of that country?
Country codes:

```
Netherlands 169

Germany 120

France 116

Spain 225

Italy 137

Russia 187

South-Korea 143

USA 201
```

(The country code for the Netherlands is 169 in the fetch function, should be 120 for Germany etc.)

```js
window.onload = function() {
 getCovidStats();
}

function getCovidStats() {
 fetch('https://coronavirus-tracker-api.herokuapp.com/v2/locations/169')
 .then(function(resp) { return resp.json() })
 .then(function(data) {
  let population = data.location.country_population;
  let update = data.location.last_updated;
  let confirmedCases = data.location.latest.confirmed;
  let deaths = data.location.latest.deaths;

  document.getElementById('population').innerHTML = population.toLocaleString('en');
  document.getElementById('update').innerHTML = update.substr(0, 10);
  document.getElementById('cases').innerHTML = confirmedCases.toLocaleString('en');
  document.getElementById('deaths').innerHTML = deaths.toLocaleString('en');
  document.getElementById('percent').innerHTML = ((Number(deaths)/Number(confirmedCases))*100).toLocaleString("en", {minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2}) + "%";




 })
 .catch(function() {
  console.log("error");
 })
 setTimeout(getCovidStats, 43200000) // update every 12 hours
}
```

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

html {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}
h1, h2 {
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 300;
 text-align: center;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
 font-size: 250%;
}

.title {
 background: linear-gradient(to right, #feb47b, #ff7e5f);
 padding: 20px;
}

.subtitle {
 padding: 20px;
 font-size: 150%;
}

div {
 padding: 20px;
}

.stats-container {
 text-align: center;
 float: right;
 display: inline-block;
}
.location-container {
 display: inline-block;
}
.data-container {
 border: 2px solid #feb47b;
 margin-right: 30%;
 margin-left: 30%;

}
h4 {
 font-size: 85%;
  color: gray;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.footer {
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 bottom: 0;
 font-size: 75%;
 padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Name</title>

 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="masker-emoji.png">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
 <h1 class="title">Coronavirus Stats.</h1>
 <h2 class="subtitle">Subtitle</h2>
 <div class="data-container">
  <div class="stats-container">
   <h4>Tested positive</h4>
   <h1 id="cases"></h1>
   <h4>Deaths</h4>
   <h1 id="deaths"></h1>
   <h4>Death percentage</h4>
   <h1 id="percent"></h1>
  </div>
  <div class="location-container">
   <h4>Land</h4>
   <h1 id="country"><label for="Country">Country:</label>
    <select id="cars">
      <option value="Netherlands">Netherlands</option>
      <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
      <option value="France">France</option>
      <option value="Spain">Spain</option>
      <option value="Italy">Italy</option>
      <option value="Russia">Russia</option>
      <option value="South-Korea">South-Korea</option>
      <option value="USA">USA</option>
    </select></h1>
   <h4>Population</h4>
   <h1 id="population"></h1>
   <h4>Last update on</h4>
   <h1 id="update"></h1>
  </div>
 </div>
 <h1 class="footer">Footer</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why use empty H1 as placeholders? Use <a id="population></a> if you do not need text there. OR put the ID on the H4 with texts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this

Use addEventListener on select and change the values to the numbers.

I added a "Please Select"

and changed the ID from cars to `<select id="countrySel">`

```js
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
  document.getElementById("countrySel").addEventListener("change",getCovidStats);
  document.getElementById("countrySel").value="169";
  getCovidStats()
})

function getCovidStats() {
  const cc = document.getElementById("countrySel").value;
  if (cc==="") return;
  
  fetch('https://coronavirus-tracker-api.herokuapp.com/v2/locations/'+cc)
    .then(function(resp) {
      return resp.json()
    })
    .then(function(data) {
      let population = data.location.country_population;
      let update = data.location.last_updated;
      let confirmedCases = data.location.latest.confirmed;
      let deaths = data.location.latest.deaths;

      document.getElementById('population').innerHTML = population.toLocaleString('en');
      document.getElementById('update').innerHTML = update.substr(0, 10);
      document.getElementById('cases').innerHTML = confirmedCases.toLocaleString('en');
      document.getElementById('deaths').innerHTML = deaths.toLocaleString('en');
      document.getElementById('percent').innerHTML = ((Number(deaths) / Number(confirmedCases)) * 100).toLocaleString("en", {
        minimumFractionDigits: 2,
        maximumFractionDigits: 2
      }) + "%";
    })
    .catch(function() {
      console.log("error");
    })
    setInterval(getCovidStats, 43200000) // update every 12 hours
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

h1,
h2 {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 250%;
}

.title {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #feb47b, #ff7e5f);
  padding: 20px;
}

.subtitle {
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 150%;
}

div {
  padding: 20px;
}

.stats-container {
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
}

.location-container {
  display: inline-block;
}

.data-container {
  border: 2px solid #feb47b;
  margin-right: 30%;
  margin-left: 30%;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 85%;
  color: gray;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.footer {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  bottom: 0;
  font-size: 75%;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Name</title>

  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="masker-emoji.png">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <h1 class="title">Coronavirus Stats.</h1>
  <h2 class="subtitle">Subtitle</h2>
  <div class="data-container">
    <div class="stats-container">
      <h4>Tested positive</h4>
      <h1 id="cases"></h1>
      <h4>Deaths</h4>
      <h1 id="deaths"></h1>
      <h4>Death percentage</h4>
      <h1 id="percent"></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="location-container">
      <h4>Country</h4>
      <h1 id="country"><label for="countrySel">Country:</label>
        <select id="countrySel">
          <option value="">Please select</option>
          <option value="169">Netherlands</option>
          <option value="120">Germany</option>
          <option value="116">France</option>
          <option value="225">Spain</option>
          <option value="137">Italy</option>
          <option value="187">Russia</option>
          <option value="143">South-Korea</option>
          <option value="201">USA</option>
        </select>
      </h1>
      <h4>Population</h4>
      <h1 id="population"></h1>
      <h4>Last update on</h4>
      <h1 id="update"></h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h1 class="footer">Footer</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! is there a way to make them count up faster, should I do this by changing the 50 in tId = setInterval(countUp, 50); to some lower number?

Comment: see my changed code in other question. I did 300 and 10